# Can't uninstall anaconda due to ssl error

Tags: 16.04, ssh, python, uninstall, anaconda

I am trying to uninstall anaconda using

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

But I get this error again and again

```
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",),)
```

And I can't find the solution anywhere...

**EDIT**:
To give the full context - This is a problem I encountered while trying to install gensim, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338377/cant-install-gensim-with-ubuntu16-04-and-anaconda).

I didn't know which of my previous attempts are relevant for this issue and I didn't want to burden with text...

Comment: Intstall `sudo apt install openssl` first and try again.

Comment: Then, please, mention everything you have tried before, so nobody else loses time suggesting things you already tried

Comment: @M.Becerra encountered this problem when trying to install gensim, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338377/cant-install-gensim-with-ubuntu16-04-and-anaconda) and read somewhere that if I uninstall-install anaconda it might help. I dont know which of my previous attempts were relevant, but I will edit now. Thank you for the feedback.